# Breeze javascript URL on CDN

Tags: breeze, cdn

Hi am using breeze in my project,

Is there any **URL** of breeze and related JavaScript on CDN or any cloud network ?

Comment: First google then ask if you not found

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=breeze+cdn

Comment: cdnjs.com (sponsered by cloudflare) will have the latest breeze assets soon- working on a pull request now.  Current versions are a bit out of date.  The url will be:  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/breezejs/[version]/breeze.min.js

Comment: pull request:  https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/pull/4149
waiting for it to be merged...

Comment: Thanks for that Jeremy. We got pretty far behind on that long ago. Our release process already has a ton of steps and outlets; we let this slide. Seems like most people these days aren't using a CDN for breeze because I haven't been asked about this for over a year. Happy to have it as an option.

Comment: @Ward- no problem- it *should* auto update now using the npm package.  Getting confirmation on that now:  https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/pull/4151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/) (sponsered by cloudflare) hosts several versions of breezejs.

The current version (1.5.2) is here:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/breezejs/1.5.2/breeze.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/breezejs/1.5.2/breeze.base.min.js
```

cdnjs updates when the breezejs npm package is updated in a semi-automated fashion.